# Regex - letter followed by any number of digits

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to match a string with a regex condition. It doesn't seem to be working though. It will always be capital **D**

```
var string = 'D123';

var matchVar = string.match(/^D+[0-9]^/);

if(matchVar){
    alert('yes');
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/chwprLg1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the last `^` with `+` . `+` repeat the previous token one or more times. So `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits. You cud use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`

```
var matchVar = string.match(/^D+[0-9]+/);
```

Without the end of the line anchor, the above regex  would also match `D98` in `D98foobar`.

**OR**

One or more `D`'s followed by any number of digits.

```
 var matchVar = string.match(/^D+[0-9]+$/);
```

**OR**

A single letter followed by any number of digits.

```
var matchVar = string.match(/^D[0-9]+$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^D+[0-9]+$
```

Guess you wanted this.`^` asserts start of string.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/13

or

```
^D+\d+$

var string = 'D123';

var matchVar = string.match(/^D+\d+$/);

if(matchVar){
    alert('yes');
}
```